# Using case_when and between with a correspondance threshold table

Tags: r, dplyr

Good morning,

I have 2 dataframes : (25000,66) and a thershold table (10,2) containing 10 groups and the last id of each group.

In the big dataset I have one variable called `id`. It's just `id = row_number()`

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
...
25000
```

**EDIT** : Lots of answers, thank you for all your ideas. Reading I realized that I forgot an important step in my data description and I apologized.

I'm using synthetic sampling on the original `bigdataset` to genereate new points. So after sampling the `id` column looks like this :

```
id
1
2
2.1
3
3.8
4.74
5.12
6
...
25000
```

This is why I used the between clause with the `last_id` to reassign the id to their group.

Threshold table :

```
last_id   group_name
50        grp1
1500      grp2
8900      grp3
...
25000     grp10
```

I would like to add new column to the big dataset in order to have the id and the group name, based only on the condition that the id falls in the group specified range by the threshold table.

For now I wrote this :

```r
df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(group_name = case_when(id < last_id[1,1] ~ last_id[1,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[1,1], last_id[2,1]) ~ last_id[2,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[2,1], last_id[3,1]) ~ last_id[3,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[3,1], last_id[4,1]) ~ last_id[4,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[4,1], last_id[5,1]) ~ last_id[5,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[5,1], last_id[6,1]) ~ last_id[6,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[6,1], last_id[7,1]) ~ last_id[7,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[7,1], last_id[8,1]) ~ last_id[8,2],
                                                between(id, last_id[8,1], last_id[9,1]) ~ last_id[9,2],
                                                id > last_id[9,1] ~ last_id[10,2]))
    )
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error :

> Error in FUN(left, right) :    comparaison (5) ony possible for types
> list and atomic

Moreover this code looks terrible, there must be another way using apply or another dplyr function?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cut` in base R can do this relatively easily:

```
bigdataset <- data.frame(seq(1, 25000,1))
names(bigdataset) <- 'id'
thresholds <- data.frame(
                       c(50, 1500, 8900, 10000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 25000), 
                       c('grp1','grp2','grp3','grp4', 'grp5','grp6', 'grp7','grp8','grp9','grp10'))
names(thresholds) <- c('last_id','group_name')

cut(bigdataset$id, breaks=breaks=c(min(bigdataset$id),thresholds$last_id + 1), labels=thresholds$group_name[1:10], right=FALSE) -> bigdataset$group_name
```

Output:

```
> bigdataset
         id group_name
1         1       grp1
2         2       grp1
3         3       grp1
4         4       grp1
5         5       grp1
6         6       grp1
7         7       grp1
8         8       grp1
9         9       grp1
10       10       grp1
11       11       grp1
12       12       grp1
13       13       grp1
14       14       grp1
15       15       grp1
16       16       grp1
17       17       grp1
18       18       grp1
19       19       grp1
20       20       grp1
21       21       grp1
22       22       grp1
23       23       grp1
24       24       grp1
25       25       grp1
26       26       grp1
27       27       grp1
28       28       grp1
29       29       grp1
30       30       grp1
31       31       grp1
32       32       grp1
33       33       grp1
34       34       grp1
35       35       grp1
36       36       grp1
37       37       grp1
38       38       grp1
39       39       grp1
40       40       grp1
41       41       grp1
42       42       grp1
43       43       grp1
44       44       grp1
45       45       grp1
46       46       grp1
47       47       grp1
48       48       grp1
49       49       grp1
50       50       grp2
51       51       grp2
52       52       grp2
53       53       grp2
54       54       grp2
55       55       grp2
56       56       grp2
57       57       grp2
58       58       grp2
59       59       grp2
60       60       grp2
```

Note that you need to pad your thresholds with `min(bigdataset$id)`; that way you have 11 cutpoints for 10 classes.

Comment: Hello @Otto Kässi, your solution seems to be working. Can you clarify what you mean by *pad your thresholds with min() to have 11 cutpoints* ?

Comment: `?cut` actually takes the start points of groups as breakpoint parameters. That's why you need to parameterise class breakpoints like this: `breaks=c(min(bigdataset$id), thresholds$last_id)`. This allocates id's between 0 and 50 to grp1. So, instead of writing `breaks=thresholds$last_id`, I have included ("padded") an extra cutpoint `min(bigdataset$id)` in the list of breakpoints.

Comment: Row 50 of the output posted with this answer has id = 50, group = grp2. Shouldn't it be in grp1? If one changes  `breaks=` to `breaks=c(min(bigdataset$id),thresholds$last_id + 1)` id = 50 will be assigned to grp1.

Answer (score 4):

Two options with the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package:

**1) use the rolling join functionality**

```
dt <- dt2[dt1, on = .(last_id = id), roll = -Inf]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dt
>       last_id group_name
>    1:       1       grp1
>    2:       2       grp1
>    3:       3       grp1
>    4:       4       grp1
>    5:       5       grp1
>   ---                   
> 8896:    8896       grp3
> 8897:    8897       grp3
> 8898:    8898       grp3
> 8899:    8899       grp3
> 8900:    8900       grp3
> ```

**2) use the non-equi join functionality**

```
# create a 'first_id'
dt2[, first_id := shift(last_id, fill = 0)]
# perform the non-equi join
dt1[dt2, on = .(id > first_id, id <= last_id), group := group_name]
```

This method will update `dt1` instead of creating a new `data.table` and is therefor more memory efficient:

> ```
> > dt1
>         id group
>    1:    1  grp1
>    2:    2  grp1
>    3:    3  grp1
>    4:    4  grp1
>    5:    5  grp1
>   ---           
> 8896: 8896  grp3
> 8897: 8897  grp3
> 8898: 8898  grp3
> 8899: 8899  grp3
> 8900: 8900  grp3
> ```

---

Options using base R:

Pure base R with `findInterval` (which is comparable to the [`cut`-method from @ Otto Kässi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244874/2204410)):

```
df1$group_name <- df2$group_name[findInterval(df1$id, c(0, df2$last_id), left.open = TRUE)]
```

Or with base R's `merge` and `zoo::na.locf`:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "id", by.y = "last_id", all.x = TRUE)
df$group_name <- zoo::na.locf(df$group_name, fromLast = TRUE)
```

---

**Used data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:8900)
df2 <- read.table(text="last_id   group_name
50        grp1
1500      grp2
8900      grp3
", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that uses `dplyr::mutate()` to create ranges of the index variable, along with `sqldf()` and the `BETWEEN` command to join the data.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10000,max=100),1000,10))
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
library(dplyr)
grptbl <- data.frame(maxIndex = c(250,500,750,1000),groupID = c("one","two","three","four"))
grptbl <- mutate(grptbl,minIndex = if_else(is.na(lag(maxIndex)),1,lag(maxIndex)+1))

library(sqldf)
joinedData <- sqldf("select df.*, grptbl.groupID 
                    from df LEFT JOIN grptbl ON (df.id BETWEEN grptbl.minIndex AND grptbl.maxIndex)")
# print first and last rows of each group
joinedData[c(1,250,251,500,501,750,751,1000),c("group_name","X1","X2")]
```

...and the output:

```
> # print first and last rows of each group
> joinedData[c(1,250,251,500,501,750,751,1000),c("group_name","X1","X2")]
     group_name        X1        X2
1           one 53.807611 15.134119
250         one 53.016958 50.554198
251         two 36.921168  3.984325
500         two  5.974273 33.079079
501       three 75.851652 24.039047
750       three 98.233083 26.500973
751        four 14.788170 10.312172
1000       four 11.106466 41.666359
```

Another alternative with `sqldf()` is to complete the merge via the WHERE clause instead of LEFT JOIN:

```
joinedData <- sqldf("select df.*, grptbl.groupID 
                    from df, grptbl
                    WHERE df.id BETWEEN grptbl.minIndex AND grptbl.maxIndex")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went in another direction to avoid the maintenance complexity of using SQL code in R.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join instead and then use "last observation carried forward" (`na.locf` from the `zoo` package) as a workaround to fill up the missing values:

```
# some sample data
df <- data.frame(id = 1:50, val = LETTERS[1:10])
threshold <- data.frame(last_id = c(5, 15, 34, 45),
                        group_name = paste0("group_", 1:4))

df %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(threshold, by = c("id" = "last_id")) %>% 
  zoo::na.locf(fromLast = TRUE)

#>    id val group_name
#> 1   1   A    group_1
#> 2   2   B    group_1
#> 3   3   C    group_1
#> 4   4   D    group_1
#> 5   5   E    group_1
#> 6   6   F    group_2
#> 7   7   G    group_2
#> 8   8   H    group_2
#> 9   9   I    group_2
#> 10 10   J    group_2
```

Technically, by setting `fromLast = TRUE`, this actually corresponds to NOCB (next observation carried backward).

Comment: Hello @lks_swrx, I modified the question to add a sampling step I forgot, which modifies the problem quite a bit. Nevertheless I tried your solution and the returned dataframe only have 4 groups (instead of 10). After checking, only the groups whose threshold values exist in the sampled dataframe are returned in the final dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. Since you're joining at the max value for each group, you can specify `.direction = 'up'` to fill in all of the missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- left_join(df1,df2,by = c('id' = 'last_id')) %>% 
  fill(group_name, .direction = 'up')
```

df1:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(1:25000))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(last_id = c(50, 1500, 8900, 10500, 16900, 25000
), group_name = c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3", "grp4", "grp5", "grp6"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Hello Matt, thank you for your answer. I added an EDIT in my original question to add a data sampling step I missed. I can't use `left_join` because most of the original ids are not in the synthetic dataset.